# How to disable browser audio?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, audio, flash

I use Google Chrome for Windows.
How to disable or mute Flash audio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7 or Vista, you can mute individual programs in the mixer:

[image: Windows mixer, allowing per-application volume settings]

Answer (score 2):

[Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn?hl=de) allows to mute (Alt+W). So does an AddOn named [MuteTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc) for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this one is a @#$%^. I remember there was an addon for firefox to do this, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5453, it also points to this link, http://www.erigami.com/blog/disable-sound-firefox-ie/, however this isn't for chrome. WOOT got it, try [this post](http://www.chromeboard.com/showpost.php?p=40620&postcount=15), which implements the above method for chrome. If it doesn't work, I know that if you have windows 7 (maybe vista) you can expand the volume mixer and control volume on a per-application basis, so you could theoretically mute chrome alone, although that might not be what you want. Good luck!

Comment: All links are down or aren't related to the question